# Find all primes $p$ such that $x^2 \equiv 13 \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

I've took quadratic residues and found a problem solving this question. 
I searched for an answer and got a one, but it didn't convince me, maybe because the solver didn't put steps and analyze how to use theorems in such a question. Please help me!

Comment: Show what you started with "took quadratic residues", or show the answer you found and tell us which step you don't understand.

Comment: Does the phrase "quadratic reciprocity" mean anything to you?

Answer (score 1):

This can be tackled by the law of quadratic reciprocity, which says: If $p, q$ are distinct odd primes then the two statements
$$p {\rm\ is\ a\ quadratic\ residue\ of\ } q,\quad q {\rm\ is\ a\ quadratic\ residue\ of\ } p$$
are both true or both false, unless $p$ and $q$ are both congruent to 3 mod 4, in which case one statement is true and the other is false.
In our case $q = 13$, which is not congruent to 3 mod 4, so 13 is a q.r. of an odd prime $p$ iff $p$ is a q.r. of 13, that is, iff $p$ is congruent
to $\pm1, \pm 3$ or $\pm 4$ mod 13. Finally 13 is clearly a q.r. of $p = 2$.